# Message from application: You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile. (Bundler::LockfileError) during Redmin Upgrade on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, rubygems, bundler, redmine

I know this question is common but the answer doesn't always apply to each environment as Ruby/Rails/Bundler versions are different and it's tricky to fix it. My question now:

I had fully working RedMine on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I upgraded it to Redmine 5.0. Now my setup had Rails 6.1 but Ruby even though I updated it to 3.2.2, redmine still was using 2.4.5 - the old one. So I decided to update Ruby and since then it's been a nightmare.

Currently I have Ruby 3.0.6, Rails 6.1.0, Bundler 2.2.33. When I run `bundler update`, I get error as below:

```
[ 2023-04-30 16:04:16.0157 11368/7f8320cec700 age/Cor/Con/CheckoutSession.cpp:285 ]: [Client 1-267] Cannot checkout session because a spawning error occurred. The identifier of the error is 71ff3137. Please see earlier logs for details about the error.
App 21640 stdout:
App 21640 stderr: Ignoring nokogiri-1.14.3 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.14.3
App 21640 stdout:
[ 2023-04-30 16:04:46.9595 11368/7f832015d700 age/Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:304 ]: Could not spawn process for application /opt/redmine: An error occurred while starting up the preloader.
  Error ID: e7d659ed
  Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-gMxf6z.html
  Message from application: You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile. (Bundler::LockfileError)
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/lockfile_parser.rb:108:in `warn_for_outdated_bundler_version'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/lockfile_parser.rb:95:in `initialize'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/definition.rb:83:in `new'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/definition.rb:83:in `initialize'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/dsl.rb:218:in `new'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/dsl.rb:218:in `to_definition'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/dsl.rb:13:in `evaluate'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/definition.rb:35:in `build'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler.rb:135:in `definition'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler.rb:101:in `setup'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/setup.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
  /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
  /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:430:in `activate_gem'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:297:in `block in run_load_path_setup_code'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:435:in `running_bundler'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:296:in `run_load_path_setup_code'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:100:in `preload_app'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:156:in `<module:App>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:30:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<main>
```

Now, I'm surprised, why it's showing `vendor_ruby` and also why it's taking `/usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/` instead of ruby 3.0.6 as I have Ruby version globaly and locally as 3.0.6. What is the best Ruby + Rails + Bundler combination? where all are latest versions. I have tried multiple times deleting `Gemfile.lock` and rebuilding it with different bundler versions like `2.4.5` or `2.2.4` but sometimes it would show `You must use Bundler 2 or greater` even though I have greater, or sometimes it will cry for dependencies gemfile not found like `nokogiri` or something like that.

My `bundle env` file is as below for debugging help.

```
Your Gemfile lists the gem redmine_crm (>= 0) more than once.
You should probably keep only one of them.
Remove any duplicate entries and specify the gem only once.
While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of one of them later.
## Environment
```

```
Bundler       2.2.33
  Platforms   ruby, x86_64-linux
Ruby          3.0.6p216 (2023-03-30 revision 23a532679b406cb53c0edfc00c91c32a5ccd335a) [x86_64-linux]
  Full Path   /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/3.0.6/bin/ruby
  Config Dir  /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/3.0.6/etc
RubyGems      3.2.33
  Gem Home    /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/3.0.6/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0
  Gem Path    /home/ubuntu/.gem/ruby/3.0.0:/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/3.0.6/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0
  User Home   /home/ubuntu
  User Path   /home/ubuntu/.gem/ruby/3.0.0
  Bin Dir     /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/3.0.6/bin
Tools
  Git         2.17.1
  RVM         not installed
  rbenv       rbenv 1.2.0-62-ga632465
  chruby      not installed
```

```
## Bundler Build Metadata
```

```
Built At          2023-04-30
Git SHA           unknown
Released Version  false
```

```
## Bundler settings
```

```
default
  Set for your local app (/opt/redmine/.bundle/config): "2.4.12"
force_ruby_platform
  Set for the current user (/home/ubuntu/.bundle/config): true
without
  Set for your local app (/opt/redmine/.bundle/config): [:development, :test]
  Set for the current user (/home/ubuntu/.bundle/config): [:development, :test]
```

```
## Gemfile

### Gemfile
```

```rb
source 'https://rubygems.org'

#ruby '> 2.5.0', '<2.5.2'
ruby '>= 2.5.0', '< 3.2.0'
#ruby '3.0.0'
gem 'bundler', '>= 1.12.0'

#gem 'rails', '6.1.7.2'
gem 'rails', '6.1.0'
#gem 'globalid', '~> 0.4.2' if Gem.ruby_version < Gem::Version.new('2.6.0')
gem 'globalid', '~> 1.1.0'
gem 'rouge', '~> 3.28.0'
gem 'request_store', '~> 1.5.0'
gem 'mini_mime', '~> 1.1.0'
gem "actionpack-xml_parser"
gem 'roadie-rails', (Gem.ruby_version < Gem::Version.new('2.6.0') ? '~> 2.2.0' : '~> 3.0.0')
gem 'marcel'
gem "mail", "~> 2.7.1"
gem 'csv', '~> 3.2.0'
#gem 'nokogiri', (Gem.ruby_version < Gem::Version.new('2.6.0') ? '~> 1.12.5' : '~> 1.13.10')
#gem 'nokogiri', '1.13.10', force_ruby_platform: true
#gem 'nokogiri', '1.14.3'
gem 'nokogiri', '1.12.0'
gem "rexml", require: false if Gem.ruby_version >= Gem::Version.new('3.0')
gem 'i18n', '~> 1.10.0'
gem 'rbpdf', '~> 1.21.0'
gem 'addressable'
gem 'rubyzip', '~> 2.3.0'
gem 'net-smtp', '~> 0.3.0'
gem 'net-imap', '~> 0.2.2'
gem 'net-pop', '~> 0.1.1'
# Rails 6.1.6.1 does not work with Pysch 3.0.2, which is installed by default with Ruby 2.5. See https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/45590
gem 'psych', '>= 3.1.0' if Gem.ruby_version < Gem::Version.new('2.6.0')

# added by kailash
#gem 'zeitwerk', '~> 2.6', '>= 2.6.8'
gem 'zeitwerk', '~> 2.4.0'
gem 'minitest', '5.15.0'
gem 'mini_portile2', '2.6.1'
#gem 'mini_portile2', '2.8.1'
gem 'activesupport', '6.1.0'

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :x64_mingw, :mswin]

# TOTP-based 2-factor authentication
gem 'rotp', '>= 5.0.0'
gem 'rqrcode'

# Optional gem for LDAP authentication
group :ldap do
  gem 'net-ldap', '~> 0.17.0'
end

# Optional gem for exporting the gantt to a PNG file
group :minimagick do
  gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.11.0'
end

# Optional Markdown support, not for JRuby
# ToDo: Remove common_mark group when common_mark is decoupled from markdown. See defect (#36892) for more details.
gem 'redcarpet', '~> 3.5.1', groups: [:markdown, :common_mark]

# Optional CommonMark support, not for JRuby
group :common_mark do
  gem "html-pipeline", "~> 2.13.2"
  gem "commonmarker", (Gem.ruby_version < Gem::Version.new('2.6.0') ? '0.21.0' : '~> 0.23.8')
  gem "sanitize", "~> 6.0"
  gem 'deckar01-task_list', '2.3.2'
end

# Include database gems for the adapters found in the database
# configuration file
require 'erb'
require 'yaml'
database_file = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "config/database.yml")
if File.exist?(database_file)
  yaml_config = ERB.new(IO.read(database_file)).result
  database_config = YAML.respond_to?(:unsafe_load) ? YAML.unsafe_load(yaml_config) : YAML.load(yaml_config)
  adapters = database_config.values.map {|c| c['adapter']}.compact.uniq
  if adapters.any?
    adapters.each do |adapter|
      case adapter
      when 'mysql2'
        gem "mysql2", "~> 0.5.0", :platforms => [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
      when /postgresql/
        gem "pg", "~> 1.2.2", :platforms => [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
      when /sqlite3/
        gem "sqlite3", "~> 1.4.0", :platforms => [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
      when /sqlserver/
        gem "tiny_tds", "~> 2.1.2", :platforms => [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
        gem "activerecord-sqlserver-adapter", "~> 6.1.0", :platforms => [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
      else
        warn("Unknown database adapter `#{adapter}` found in config/database.yml, use Gemfile.local to load your own database gems")
      end
    end
  else
    warn("No adapter found in config/database.yml, please configure it first")
  end
else
  warn("Please configure your config/database.yml first")
end

group :development do
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.3'
  gem "yard"
end

group :test do
  gem "rails-dom-testing"
  #gem 'mocha', (Gem.ruby_version < Gem::Version.new('2.7.0') ? ['>= 1.4.0', '< 2.0.0'] : '>= 1.4.0')
  gem 'simplecov', '~> 0.21.2', :require => false
  gem "ffi", platforms: [:mingw, :x64_mingw, :mswin]
  # For running system tests
  #gem 'puma', (Gem.ruby_version < Gem::Version.new('2.7') ? '< 6.0.0' : '>= 0')
  #gem 'capybara', (if Gem.ruby_version < Gem::Version.new('2.6')
  #                   '~> 3.35.3'
  #                 elsif Gem.ruby_version < Gem::Version.new('2.7')
  #                   '~> 3.36.0'
  #                 else
  #                   '~> 3.38.0'
  #                 end)
  gem "selenium-webdriver", "~> 3.142.7"
  gem 'webdrivers', '4.6.1', require: false
  # RuboCop
  gem 'rubocop', '~> 1.26.0'
  gem 'rubocop-performance', '~> 1.13.0'
  gem 'rubocop-rails', '~> 2.14.0'
end

local_gemfile = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "Gemfile.local")
if File.exist?(local_gemfile)
  eval_gemfile local_gemfile
end

# Load plugins' Gemfiles
Dir.glob File.expand_path("../plugins/*/{Gemfile,PluginGemfile}", __FILE__) do |file|
  eval_gemfile file
end
```

```
### Gemfile.local
```

```rb
gem 'puma'
```

```
### plugins/redmine_agile/Gemfile
```

```rb
gem "redmine_crm"
```

```
### plugins/redmine_checklists/Gemfile
```

```rb
gem 'redmine_crm'
```

```
### plugins/redmine_cms/Gemfile
```

```rb
gem "sass", "~> 3.4.22"
gem "redmine_crm"
```

```
### plugins/redmine_drive/Gemfile
```

```rb
gem 'redmine_crm'
```

```
### plugins/redmine_people/Gemfile
```

```rb
gem 'redmine_crm'
gem 'vcard', (RUBY_VERSION > '2.0' ? '>= 0' : '~> 0.2.16')
```

```
### plugins/redmine_questions/Gemfile
```

```rb
gem "redmine_crm"
```

```
### plugins/redmine_resources/Gemfile
```

```rb
gem 'redmine_crm'
```

```
### plugins/redmine_zenedit/Gemfile
```

```rb
gem 'redmine_crm'
```

```
### plugins/redmineup_tags/Gemfile
```

```rb
gem 'redmine_crm'
```

```
### Gemfile.lock
```

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actioncable (6.1.0)
      actionpack (= 6.1.0)
      activesupport (= 6.1.0)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
      websocket-driver (>= 0.6.1)
    actionmailbox (6.1.0)
      actionpack (= 6.1.0)
      activejob (= 6.1.0)
      activerecord (= 6.1.0)
      activestorage (= 6.1.0)
      activesupport (= 6.1.0)
      mail (>= 2.7.1)
    actionmailer (6.1.0)
      actionpack (= 6.1.0)
      actionview (= 6.1.0)
      activejob (= 6.1.0)
      activesupport (= 6.1.0)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
    actionpack (6.1.0)
      actionview (= 6.1.0)
      activesupport (= 6.1.0)
      rack (~> 2.0, >= 2.0.9)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.2.0)
    actionpack-xml_parser (2.0.1)
      actionpack (>= 5.0)
      railties (>= 5.0)
    actiontext (6.1.0)
      actionpack (= 6.1.0)
      activerecord (= 6.1.0)
      activestorage (= 6.1.0)
      activesupport (= 6.1.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.8.5)
    actionview (6.1.0)
      activesupport (= 6.1.0)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubi (~> 1.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.1, >= 1.2.0)
    activejob (6.1.0)
      activesupport (= 6.1.0)
      globalid (>= 0.3.6)
    activemodel (6.1.0)
      activesupport (= 6.1.0)
    activerecord (6.1.0)
      activemodel (= 6.1.0)
      activesupport (= 6.1.0)
    activestorage (6.1.0)
      actionpack (= 6.1.0)
      activejob (= 6.1.0)
      activerecord (= 6.1.0)
      activesupport (= 6.1.0)
      marcel (~> 0.3.1)
      mimemagic (~> 0.3.2)
    activesupport (6.1.0)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      i18n (>= 1.6, < 2)
      minitest (>= 5.1)
      tzinfo (~> 2.0)
      zeitwerk (~> 2.3)
    addressable (2.8.4)
      public_suffix (>= 2.0.2, < 6.0)
    ast (2.4.2)
    builder (3.2.4)
    childprocess (3.0.0)
    chunky_png (1.4.0)
    commonmarker (0.23.9)
    concurrent-ruby (1.2.2)
    crass (1.0.6)
    css_parser (1.14.0)
      addressable
    csv (3.2.6)
    deckar01-task_list (2.3.2)
      html-pipeline
    digest (3.1.1)
    docile (1.4.0)
    erubi (1.12.0)
    ffi (1.15.5)
    globalid (1.1.0)
      activesupport (>= 5.0)
    html-pipeline (2.13.2)
      activesupport (>= 2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.4)
    htmlentities (4.3.4)
    i18n (1.10.0)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    liquid (2.6.3)
    listen (3.8.0)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.10, >= 0.10.3)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.10)
    loofah (2.20.0)
      crass (~> 1.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.7.1)
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.1)
    marcel (0.3.3)
      mimemagic (~> 0.3.2)
    method_source (1.0.0)
    mimemagic (0.3.10)
      nokogiri (~> 1)
      rake
    mini_magick (4.11.0)
    mini_mime (1.1.2)
    mini_portile2 (2.6.1)
    minitest (5.15.0)
    mysql2 (0.5.5)
    net-imap (0.2.3)
      digest
      net-protocol
      strscan
    net-ldap (0.17.1)
    net-pop (0.1.2)
      net-protocol
    net-protocol (0.2.1)
      timeout
    net-smtp (0.3.3)
      net-protocol
    nio4r (2.5.9)
    nokogiri (1.12.0)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.6.1)
      racc (~> 1.4)
    parallel (1.23.0)
    parser (3.2.2.1)
      ast (~> 2.4.1)
    public_suffix (5.0.1)
    puma (6.2.2)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
    racc (1.6.2)
    rack (2.2.7)
    rack-test (2.1.0)
      rack (>= 1.3)
    rails (6.1.0)
      actioncable (= 6.1.0)
      actionmailbox (= 6.1.0)
      actionmailer (= 6.1.0)
      actionpack (= 6.1.0)
      actiontext (= 6.1.0)
      actionview (= 6.1.0)
      activejob (= 6.1.0)
      activemodel (= 6.1.0)
      activerecord (= 6.1.0)
      activestorage (= 6.1.0)
      activesupport (= 6.1.0)
      bundler (>= 1.15.0)
      railties (= 6.1.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0)
    rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.6)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.5.0)
      loofah (~> 2.19, >= 2.19.1)
    railties (6.1.0)
      actionpack (= 6.1.0)
      activesupport (= 6.1.0)
      method_source
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (~> 1.0)
    rainbow (3.1.1)
    rake (13.0.6)
    rb-fsevent (0.11.2)
    rb-inotify (0.10.1)
      ffi (~> 1.0)
    rbpdf (1.21.1)
      htmlentities
      rbpdf-font (~> 1.19.0)
    rbpdf-font (1.19.1)
    redcarpet (3.5.1)
    redmine_crm (0.0.59)
      liquid (< 2.6.4)
      rails
      rubyzip
    regexp_parser (2.8.0)
    request_store (1.5.1)
      rack (>= 1.4)
    rexml (3.2.5)
    roadie (5.1.0)
      css_parser (~> 1.4)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
    roadie-rails (3.0.0)
      railties (>= 5.1, < 7.1)
      roadie (~> 5.0)
    rotp (6.2.2)
    rouge (3.28.0)
    rqrcode (2.1.2)
      chunky_png (~> 1.0)
      rqrcode_core (~> 1.0)
    rqrcode_core (1.2.0)
    rubocop (1.26.1)
      parallel (~> 1.10)
      parser (>= 3.1.0.0)
      rainbow (>= 2.2.2, < 4.0)
      regexp_parser (>= 1.8, < 3.0)
      rexml
      rubocop-ast (>= 1.16.0, < 2.0)
      ruby-progressbar (~> 1.7)
      unicode-display_width (>= 1.4.0, < 3.0)
    rubocop-ast (1.28.0)
      parser (>= 3.2.1.0)
    rubocop-performance (1.13.3)
      rubocop (>= 1.7.0, < 2.0)
      rubocop-ast (>= 0.4.0)
    rubocop-rails (2.14.2)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      rack (>= 1.1)
      rubocop (>= 1.7.0, < 2.0)
    ruby-progressbar (1.13.0)
    rubyzip (2.3.2)
    sanitize (6.0.1)
      crass (~> 1.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.12.0)
    sass (3.4.25)
    selenium-webdriver (3.142.7)
      childprocess (>= 0.5, < 4.0)
      rubyzip (>= 1.2.2)
    simplecov (0.21.2)
      docile (~> 1.1)
      simplecov-html (~> 0.11)
      simplecov_json_formatter (~> 0.1)
    simplecov-html (0.12.3)
    simplecov_json_formatter (0.1.4)
    sprockets (4.2.0)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (>= 2.2.4, < 4)
    sprockets-rails (3.4.2)
      actionpack (>= 5.2)
      activesupport (>= 5.2)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    strscan (3.0.6)
    thor (1.2.1)
    timeout (0.3.2)
    tzinfo (2.0.6)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    unicode-display_width (2.4.2)
    vcard (0.3.0)
    webdrivers (4.6.1)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6)
      rubyzip (>= 1.3.0)
      selenium-webdriver (>= 3.0, < 4.0)
    websocket-driver (0.7.5)
      websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
    websocket-extensions (0.1.5)
    yard (0.9.34)
    zeitwerk (2.4.2)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  actionpack-xml_parser
  activesupport (= 6.1.0)
  addressable
  bundler (>= 1.12.0)
  commonmarker (~> 0.23.8)
  csv (~> 3.2.0)
  deckar01-task_list (= 2.3.2)
  ffi
  globalid (~> 1.1.0)
  html-pipeline (~> 2.13.2)
  i18n (~> 1.10.0)
  listen (~> 3.3)
  mail (~> 2.7.1)
  marcel
  mini_magick (~> 4.11.0)
  mini_mime (~> 1.1.0)
  mini_portile2 (= 2.6.1)
  minitest (= 5.15.0)
  mysql2 (~> 0.5.0)
  net-imap (~> 0.2.2)
  net-ldap (~> 0.17.0)
  net-pop (~> 0.1.1)
  net-smtp (~> 0.3.0)
  nokogiri (= 1.12.0)
  puma
  rails (= 6.1.0)
  rails-dom-testing
  rbpdf (~> 1.21.0)
  redcarpet (~> 3.5.1)
  redmine_crm
  request_store (~> 1.5.0)
  rexml
  roadie-rails (~> 3.0.0)
  rotp (>= 5.0.0)
  rouge (~> 3.28.0)
  rqrcode
  rubocop (~> 1.26.0)
  rubocop-performance (~> 1.13.0)
  rubocop-rails (~> 2.14.0)
  rubyzip (~> 2.3.0)
  sanitize (~> 6.0)
  sass (~> 3.4.22)
  selenium-webdriver (~> 3.142.7)
  simplecov (~> 0.21.2)
  tzinfo-data
  vcard
  webdrivers (= 4.6.1)
  yard
  zeitwerk (~> 2.4.0)

RUBY VERSION
   ruby 3.0.6p216

BUNDLED WITH
   2.2.33
```

Comment: In the gemfile, try changing to `ruby '3.0.6'`. Also check if there is a `.ruby-version` file and whether it species a different ruby version. It's best to use a version manager like `rvm` or `rbenv` to manage the versions.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I'm using rbenv. .ruvy-version shows 3.0.6 and ruby -v also shows 3.0.6.

Comment: Are you doing anything with `sudo`?